# MatLab: Create matrix row element if row elements of two previous matrices are identical

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix, intersection

Sorry for the title. I could not think of something better.

I have the following problem.

I have two four-column matrices build up like this:

Property | X | Y | Z

The two matrices have different sizes, since matrix 1 has a large amount of additional rows compared to matrix 2.

What I want to do is the following:

I need to create a third matrix that only features those rows (of the large matrix) that are identical in columns X, Y and Z to rows in matrix2(the property column is always different).

I tried an if-statement but it did not really work out due to my programming syntax. Has somebody a tip?

Thank you!

I tried something like this: (in this case A is the larger matrix and I want its property column for X,Y,Z-positions that are identical to another matrix B.. I am terrible with the MatLab-syntax..

```
if (A(:,2) == B(:,2) and (A(:,3) == B(:,3) and  (A(:,4) == B(:,4)) 

newArray(:,1) = A(:,1);
```

end

Comment: I fear that in the way depicted in the code example it might cancel since A and B are of different size and it cannot really compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option to find the desired rows, and then use that as an index to build the result:

```
ind = ismember(A(:,2:4), B(:,2:4), 'rows');
C = A(ind,:);
```

I have assumed that a row of `A` is selected if its last three columns match those of *any* row of `B`.